# Flutter MethodChannel nested values: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Map<String, double>>>'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing a Flutter Plugin that sends a List of Maps (`List<Map<String, double>>`) from the Platform specific side. On the Platform specific side, I'm sending these Objects using the Default Message Codec.

```
// (example: Android side)

List<Map<String, Double>> out = new ArrayList<>();
... fill the map ...
result.success(out);
```

I'm receiving these values as follows on the Dart side:

```
static Future<List<Map<String, double>>> getListOfMaps() async {
    var traces = await _channel.invokeMethod('getListOfMaps');
    print(traces); // works
    return traces;
}
```

Printing the values gives the correct values. However, on the Function Return, I'm getting the following Error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Map<String, double>>>'` on run-time, indicating that the cast from the dynamic value to the specific `Map<String, double>` didn't work.

How do I cast nested values coming from MethodChannels correctly in Dart?

Comment: "indicating that the cast" what cast? You mean implicit? For casting nested values you need to iterate the values and cast them individually.

Comment: I know I can _kinda_ make it work by doing `List<dynamic> traces = await _channel.invokeMethod(...); return traces.cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();`. Do I really need to iterate everything just in order to assign the correct runtime type to the values?

Comment: "just in order" :D In Dart 2 types are binding. Just claiming that a value has some types isn't enough, they really need to have that type. The maps in the list are `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` of you want them to be `Map<String,double>` you need to cast each entry in `traces`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I have to cast every value with unknown runtime type individually to the expected type.

```
static Future<List<Map<String, double>>> getListOfMaps() async {
    List<dynamic> traces = await _channel.invokeMethod(...);
    return traces
        .cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>()
        .map((trace) => trace.cast<String, double>())
         .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use [`invokeListMethod`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/invokeListMethod.html):

> Since invokeMethod can only return dynamic maps, we instead create a new typed list using List.cast.

```dart
var channel = MethodChannel('foo_channel');
var list = await channel.invokeListMethod<Map<String, double>>('methodInJava');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```dart
List<Map<String, Double>> newTraces = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(traces))
```

for me i use it in another scenarios an it works